# Splitting Date/Time into 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have code that outputs the date and time into column A, but I would like for them to be separate (Date in column A, Time in Column B). I tried to figure this out with recording a macro and doing the delimiting process within Excel, but it didn't work like I wanted.

Mainly what I want to know is if this is possible, or I should try alternative coding to separate them to begin with?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim dTime As Date
Range("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"

Range("A1").Select
Set Cell = [A1]

For dTime = "3/01/2013 12:00:00 AM" To "3/02/2013 11:55:00 PM" Step "00:05"
ActiveCell.Value = dTime
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next dTime

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this need to be done via macro? Could you use a combination of formulas and settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Format(Expression,[format])` to format the values before putting it in the cell. See the updated code below (feel free to update the formats as you see fit)

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim dTime As Date
Dim x As Integer

x = 1

For dTime = "3/01/2013 12:00:00 AM" To "3/02/2013 11:55:00 PM" Step TimeValue("00:05:00")
    ' Sets the date in the cell of the first column
    Cells(x,1).Value = DateValue(dTime)

    ' Sets the time in the cell of the second column
    Cells(x,2).Value = TimeValue(dTime)

    ' Increment the row position
    x = x + 1
Next dTime
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should incorporate part of your last answer into this one. Avoid Selecting/Activating anything. Your answer here works, but selecting the cells and writing to the activecell could be easily avoided.

Comment: 100% right @Head of Catering.. i was in a rush and just updated the OP's code.

Comment: Actually this is a bad solution as `Format()` returns a `String` for both (date and time). You cannot calculate with these strings anymore! **Never convert a date into a string unless it is for displaying purposes only.** Intead always return a real date value (`Long` or if it is with time `Double`) and use the `.NumberFormat` to change how it displays in Excel: `MyDate = Int(dTime)` and `MyTime = dTime - Int(dTime)` then `.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"` as desired.