# VB script or similar to split one column "timestamp" into two "date" and "time"

Tags: excel, vba

I've imported a lot of data into excel but the first column is timestamp data all in one column

```
Timestamp
```

1. 03/04/17 00:00
2. 03/04/17 01:00
3. 03/04/17 02:00
4. 03/04/17 02:00

if someone would be kind enough to suggest the quickest way of running a script or similar to split into two columns "date" and "time" that would be great thanks.

Comment: Use the LEFT/RIGHT formula to extract x number of characters.

Comment: Is the information in the column a date/time or is it just a text value?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731795/splitting-date-time-into-2-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting Date/Time into 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731795/splitting-date-time-into-2-columns)

Comment: @FluffyKitten and XLmatters - That question / answer generated a **series** of dates and times, i.e. all times between two dates with 5 minute increments, it doesn't handle a "non-series".  (It may give clues, but is definitely not a duplicate.)

Comment: Maybe use the Excel built-in function: `Data > Text to Columns`, pick space as delimiter.  This will quickly split the date and time but you will need to format the cells to the way you want.

Comment: Or, `=QUOTIENT(R1C1)` to get the dates, and `=R1C1-QUOTIENT(R1C1)` to get the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy all the dates and times into a text editor, replace space with `,` then import data, then text in excel the text file you have created with the commas, select comma as the delimiter, now you should have two columns of this data without using any macro or formula to do so.

Answer (score 0):

"Use the LEFT/RIGHT formula to extract x number of characters" unfortunately this data is in a time format of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm so left and right formula pulls out a timestamp number not the time.

What I found worked was

=TEXT(A1, "hh:mm") pulls out the time into another cell
=TEXT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy") pulls out the date only.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in column A, I would use the following functions:

in column B: =DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yy")) format as date

in column C: =TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm")) format as time

this way the data remains as a date and a time value respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The date/time is just a number with the integer representing the date, and the remainder representing the time of day.
So today at midnight (4th September 2017) is represented by the number 42982 - being that number of days since 1st January 1900.

Today at midday is represented by the number 42982.5 - halfway through the day.

So, with your date/time in cell A1 you can use `=INT(A1)` and format as a date to return just the date.

You can use `=A1-INT(A1)` and format as a time to return just the time.
  Note that this loses the date information from the number - midday is now represented by `0.5` which is the same as `00/01/1900 12:00`.

It may be better to add the date/time to both columns and format one as a date only and the other as the time.  Any calculations that span more than one day will then be correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Use an Array**
Here you find some code lines using an array over the source data in column A. The splitted values of date and time portion are written back into the adjacent two columns B and C.

**Remark** It's always a much better performance to use array loops instead of looping directly thru ranges.

**Code**

```
Sub splitDateValues()
  Dim vArr      As Variant   ' array based on source data in columns A (to C)
  Dim temp      As Variant   ' dates split
  Dim i         As Long      ' row number
  Dim lstRow    As Long      ' last row in source data
  Dim rngSource As Range     ' source data (in column A, including a head line in A1)
' A. define data source range (column A) and include adjacent columns B and C to write back split values
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDateSheet")
    ' find last row in source
      lstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' set source range including columns B and C
       Set rngSource = .Range("A1:C" & lstRow)
  End With

  ' B. build one based array vArr out of source data range
  ' (instead of looping directly thru range)
    vArr = rngSource.Value

  ' C. loop thru array and split values (beginning in second line)
    vArr(1, 2) = "Date": vArr(1, 3) = "Time"
    For i = 2 To UBound(vArr)

    ' split date values into temp variable consisting of two portions
      temp = Split(vArr(i, 1) & String(2, " "), " ")
      If temp(1) = "" Then temp(1) = "0:0:0"
    ' one based 2-dimensional array vArr gets zero based split values
      vArr(i, 2) = temp(0)  ' date Portion temp(0)
      vArr(i, 3) = temp(1)  ' time Portion temp(1)

    Next i

  ' D. write array back to worksheet
    rngSource = vArr

End Sub
```