# Separating the date and time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In my data, the date-time format is `15-02-2019 19:56` in a single column.
 I want to separate the date and time separate column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting Date/Time into 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731795/splitting-date-time-into-2-columns)

Comment: Copy the content of the cell to the other column. Format the one cell as a data and the other cell as time. Excel stores all date-time information as a very long number. What you see is a result of how the cell is formatted, not what^s stored in the cell.

Comment: @newguy The duplicate you linked is actually a bad solution as `Format()` returns a `String` for both (date and time) and let Excel guess to convert it to the right date value. **Never convert a date into a string unless it is for displaying purposes only.** Intead always return a real date value (`Long` or if it is with time `Double`) and use the number format to change how it displays in Excel. If you use strings, that makes calculating with it impossible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when using dates/date-times then what Excel **shows** in the cell is not what Excel actually **saves** as value in the cell. The value that Excel saves for that date is actually `43511,83056` which is the number of days since `1900-01-01`. So time is a part of one day and is therefore represented by the part after the comma of that value.

[image]

So you can either use …

- `=INT(B1)` to get only the date (and format the cell as date)
- `=B1-INT(B1)` to get only the time (and format the cell as time)

Or just use the same value as in column B (`=B1` in C and D) and just format one as date and one as time.

---

In VBA you can use the same technique:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitDateAndTime()
    Dim MyDateTime As Date
    MyDateTime = Range("B1").Value

    'get date
    Range("C1").Value = Int(MyDateTime)
    Range("C1").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

    'get time
    Range("D1").Value = MyDateTime - Int(MyDateTime)
    Range("D1").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming your date and time in cell A1,

use the below formula in B1

```
=--TEXT(A1,"dd/MMM/yyyy")
```

and use the below formula in C1

```
=--TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")
```

and select B1 and C1 and customize your date and time format.

[image]

Comment: This is no good idea, as the format used in `=--TEXT(A1,"dd/MMM/yyyy")` must depend on the localization that the operating system uses otherwise you get an `#VALUE!` error. • Since globalization is *now* this will easily fail. • **Never convert a date into a string unless it is for displaying purposes only**